# Outputting on a file

Tags: python, python-3.x

This is my code

```
sentext = open("urSentence.txt", "w")
UserSen = input("Enter your sentence of your choice, ")
print (UserSen)
sentext.close()
postext = open("ThePos.txt", "w")
listSplit = UserSen.split()
X = {} #this will make the words in a sentence assigned to a number
position=[]
for i,j in enumerate(listSplit): #"i" will count how many words there are in the sentence
    if j in X:
        position.append(X[j])
    else:
        X[j]=i
        position.append(i)
print (position)
postext.close()
```

It makes the files but it doesn't save anything in them. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Doesn't save *what* on to it? You never write anything to or read anything from the files.

Comment: You are just opening and closing the file

Comment: f.write('This is a test\n') use this to save text inside file

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You never wrote to any file in any way. You can do that in a few ways. Since you're already using what looks like Python 3's `print` function, try the `file` parameter:

```
print(UserSen, file=sentext)

...

print(position, file=postext)
```

Comment: Never knew print had an option to write to file. Good to know! +1

Answer (score 1):

The `print` function won't write to the file.  You need to explicitly write to it.

```
sentext = open("urSentence.txt", "w")
UserSen = input("Enter your sentence of your choice, ")
sentext.write(UserSen)
sentext.close()
```

and similarly:

```
postext = open("ThePos.txt", "w")
...
postext.write(str(position))
postext.close()
```

Comment: `position` is a list. You can't directly `write` that to a file.